# Is tkinter different under windows and linux?

Tags: linux, windows, tkinter, platform

Obviously Tkinter code under linux and windows are different, but I have never seen a tutorial or documentation that mentions that. Most books on python and tkinter are written for linux platforms. I wonder if there are any books written specifically for windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not that obvious: the code itself is really the same but, of course, the GUI is builded with different libraries in runtime. The result is that the appearance of the GUI change in different OSs.